# How do I count for async task failures when working with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with firebase and redux for my react app. Due to a mistake I've made I've reached my daily quote on Firebase but that exposed a weakness in my code because now the whole app doesn't load, with the error being that I've reached my daily quota.
I've tried to fix it by having a catch block for the request that just logs the error but that doesn't really solve the issue.
I'm not quite sure how to approach this as I'm new to React and Redux. If the request fails, then my data now equals... What?

This is my code for one of my actions (one of a few similar requests):

```
export const fetchWords = projectID => async dispatch => {
  const db = firebase.firestore();

  const data = await db
    .collection("names")
    .where("project_ID", "==", projectID)
    .orderBy("total_score", "desc")
    .get()
    .catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err)
    });

  const docsData = [];
  data.docs.map(doc => {
    docsData.push(doc.data());
  });

  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_WORDS,
    payload: docsData
  });
};
```

It currently fails saying `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'docs' of undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason you're getting an error is because the `data` object has not been defined when the exception is caught.

You could either check that `data` is not `null` or `undefinfed` before you try and access the `data.docs` property or an alternative would be to use the `.then()` callback instead.

```
export const fetchWords = projectID => async dispatch => {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const docsData = [];

  db.collection("names")
    .where("project_ID", "==", projectID)
    .orderBy("total_score", "desc")
    .get()
    .then(data => data.docs.map(doc => docsData.push(doc.data())))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_WORDS,
    payload: docsData
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = await db
    .collection("names")
    .where("project_ID", "==", projectID)
    .orderBy("total_score", "desc")
    .get()
    .catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err)
    });
```

here if promise is rejected data will always be undefined. so it's useful to have check for data for valid value before using it.

```
  if(data !== undefined){
    data.docs.map(doc => {
        docsData.push(doc.data());
      });
    }
```